# PHP Open URL and Redirect

Tags: php, javascript, html, shopping-cart

I am using an SMS payment system called ImpulsePay, but the secure method only, in effect gives a URL.

[Secure Method](http://uk.impulsepay.com/10561?URL=Y)

How can I implement it so that the URL given is either a link or, even better, redirected to the payment page?

Ultimately, I'd like the original site to have the "Click Here To Pay With An SMS", but a few page redirects shouldn't be an issue at this early development stage.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain in a better way? The question is still quite ambiguous...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code redirects the user to a page:
   `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

However this function must be called before any output is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//Redirect browser
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

//File get contents
$url = 'http://www.example.com/redireccionar.php';
$page = file_get_contents($url);
echo $page;

//cURL
$c = curl_init('http://www.example.com/redireccionar.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo $page;

//http Client
$url = 'http://www.example.com/redireccionar.php';
require_once 'HTTP/Client.php';
$client = new HTTP_Client();
$client->get($url);
$page = $client->currentResponse();
echo $page['body'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that URL, it seems that you have to call the URL you've posted to get a Payment link? I would use PHP cURL bindings to get the contents generated by that URL.

Example here, http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

and then use a header() redirect.